# Set the value in html text box and dropdown with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In html we use to write like this `<input type="text" value="8">`. I am facing two problems while I am doing it using angular js tags.

1. I want to set some value which I am taking from database like `value=8`.
2. And I am using one drop down in this form. I want to auto select some value which is set in database.

```xhtml
<form id="attendanceSheet" name="attendanceSheet" ng-submit="fillUpTimeSheet(attendanceSheet.$valid)" >                 
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="resource in resources">                          
            <td data-title="'Working Hours'" style="text-align:center" ng-if="resource.isBillable == 1">{{resource.billable_hours}}h&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" style="width: 55px;" min="0" max="8" ng-init="timeSheet[$index] = {}" ng-model="timeSheet[$index].billableHour" required></td>                         
            <td data-title="'Non Billable Resource'" style="text-align:center" ng-if="resource.isBillable == 1"><select data-ng-options="o.resource_name for o in nonBillableResources" style="width: 150px;" ng-model="timeSheet[$index].nonBillableResource"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

To set the value I tried like this .. `value="resource.id"` OR `ng-init="timeSheet[$index] = {resource.id}"`

Please I need help.

Comment: angular binds the entered/selected value to a model, using ng-model. It does that in *both* directions. So, simply make sure that the value referenced by ng-model contains what you want to display/select in the input/select. Don't use the `value` field of the input.

Comment: Ok.. I will try and let you know

Comment: I have used `ng-model="resource.billable_hours"` so, now I am getting the value in text box. But when I submit the form I get null object.

Comment: I am using `ng-repeat="resource in resources"` because many records are available in db. When I remove `ng-repeat="resource in resources"` then I get the value after submiting the form.